# Why can't I add an image on top of my Matplotlib/Cartopy map?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, cartopy

I am working on a project that involves plotting data on a map with Cartopy.

Everything has been working so far, but I have been refactoring the code to make different functions callable by other parts of the program. So to that end, I have one function which adds my background to the map, and another which adds a placemarker at a specified lat/lon. Obviously, I want the placemarker above the background, but I can't seem to make it work.

For the background, I want to be able to use Cartopy stock images or web map tiles. The problem is the same either way, so I am using the Cartopy background for current testing purpose. Here is that function:

```
def custom_background(self, source_point):
    cartmap = self.plot
    source_point = source_point.split(" ")
    source_point = (float(source_point[0]), float(source_point[1]))
    dx = 2.5
    dy = 5
    pad = 0.5
    lon_min, lon_max = source_point[0]-dx, source_point[0]+dx
    lat_min, lat_max = source_point[1]-dy, source_point[1]+dy
    area = 4*dx*dy
    zoom = self.get_zoom(area) ##only relevant when using a map tile
    cartmap.set_extent([lat_min-pad, lat_max+pad, lon_min-pad, lon_max+pad])
    #~ cartmap.add_image(self.tile, zoom)
    cartmap.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, zorder=1)
    return cartmap
```

Here is the placemark function:

```
def add_point_icon(self, x, y, cartmap):
    src_point = np.array(Image.open('icons/icon63.png'))
    im = OffsetImage(src_point, zoom=1, alpha=1.0, zorder=3)
    ab = AnnotationBbox(im, (x,y), xycoords='data', frameon=False)
    cartmap.add_artist(ab)
```

Both of these are called one after the other like so:

```
    cartmap = self.custom_background(mysrc)
    #~ cartmap=self.plot
    self.add_point_icon(x1, y1, cartmap)
```

Results:

If I run the code as it is, this is how the map looks:

[image: map with background]

If I change it to (i.e. bypassing the function which draws the background):

```
    #~ cartmap = self.custom_background(mysrc)
    cartmap=self.plot
    self.add_point_icon(x1, y1, cartmap)
```

Then I get:

[image]

Why can't I get the red "plus" sign to show up on top of the map? I've tried setting the "zorder" parameter of the different objects and it doesn't seem to do anything. I'm at a complete loss right now. Any help would be hugely appreciated, thanks.

Edit: perhaps I should also include the lines which create the subplot:

```
def __init__(self, mylevs):
    self.fig, self.header, self.footer, self.plot, self.legend = 
        self.create_spec()

def create_spec(self):
    """Define layout of figure"""

    #left column: header, footer, plt
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
    layout = 1
    if layout == 1: #Default
        widths = [8,1]
        heights = [2, 10, 3]
        column_border = 0.75
        pad = 0.1
        colorbar_width = 0.05
        spec = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=1, nrows=3, width_ratios = [1], height_ratios=heights, left=0.1, right = column_border)
        #right column: colorbar
        spec2 = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=1, nrows=1, width_ratios = [1], height_ratios=[1], left=column_border+pad, right=column_border+pad+colorbar_width)

        header = plt.subplot(spec[0,0])
        footer = plt.subplot(spec[2,0])
        plot = plt.subplot(spec[1,0], projection=cimgt.OSM().crs)
        legend = plt.subplot(spec2[0,0])

    return fig, header, footer, plot, legend
```

Comment: I wonder if the sign is being drawn, but outside of the extent of the map you're producing? This would make it appear that it wasn't being drawn. To quickly check this, you could replace the line `cartmap.set_extent([...])` with `cartmap.set_global()`. If the sign appears, but elsewhere on the map, then you'll need to transform the sign's `(x, y)` point value into your map's projection (a good place to do this would be in the method `add_point_icon`).

Comment: This was it. It wasn't that I needed to transform the point, but that I needed to change the projection being used in the creation of the axis.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that in switching back to the Cartopy stock background from the map tiles, I forgot to switch the projection from ccrs.OSM() back to ccrs.PlateCarree(). In the map tile projection, the placemark was being plotted outside the viewing window.